# Many UIView animation causing performance problem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, uiviewanimation

I have an object which does animation... If there are many(more than 25) objects are doing animation at the same time it is causing jerk while dragging... I am creating animation using below code in each object. How can I improve performance?

```
#define DEFAULT_ANIM_SPPED 0.6
#define INFINATE_VALUE 1e100f

- (void)startAnimating
{
    mBackgroundImageView.frame = mOriginalFrame;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINATE_VALUE];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:DEFAULT_ANIM_SPPED];   

    CGRect tempFrame=mBackgroundImageView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin.y -= mAnimationOffset;
    mBackgroundImageView.frame=tempFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating animation for each view, try having one animation block that animates multiple views, for example in their common superview. I'm not sure it will make enough improvement for 25 views for your case.

Comment: I don't see why you can't make subclasses animate while superclass itself is not involved. Change the frames of subclasses in an animated block in their superclass.